# how do I see sonarqube time machine reports for a specific date in past

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We are using sonarqube 4.5.5, could someone please tell me how do I see my past reports from few days back like at the specific date. In the drop down I can only see delata from yesterday and 10 days back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see previous analysis values. SonarQube 4.5.5 only stores the current measure value and its differentials.

Comment: This answer is already two years old. Does it still apply to current version (7.7) of SonarQube?

Comment: Yep. Pretty much.